# How do you ensure that the MVC entities are in-sync with the database at run-time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I have a simple database first MVC application using Entity Framework.
I'm using `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` in the View to capture any errors from the Controller.  The Controller queries the database based on an id and creates an object based on the entity and then returns this to the View.

Recently users of the applications were getting unhandled exceptions. This was tracked to a field being removed from a database table, and becoming out of sync with the entity model (bad change management I know!).  The error was raised by the View when it tries access the removed data field, although the View thinks the model is valid.

How can I ensure that the entity is in-sync with the database using the controller at run-time so that I can better manage the error.
Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to manage the error?  You can't change the entity at run-time so I'm not sure what you're expecting to do differently.

Comment: I don't want to change the structure of the entity.  I just want to know that it is up to date.  Other wise the View will still think the model is valid, until it tires to access a member/property unexpectedly.  This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: My point is, if the entity _is not_ up-to-date what do you intend to do?  You're already getting an error, just maybe not as quickly as you want.

Comment: If I know that the entity is invalid then I would set the error conditions for the View to inform the user gracefully.  Currently the view will just fail.

Answer (score 0):

First you must check if your entity is still existent on your context:

```
existingCaseItem = Context.CaseItems.Where(ci => ci.InventoryItem.Id == caseItem.InventoryItem.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

if `existingCaseItem` is different than `null`, then it is a valid entity. Otherwise not.

To know if there have been changes since last time you got a fresh reference from the database to compare with yours.

If you are using WCF, I recommend throwing something like a custom exception:

```
if (existingCaseItem == null)
{
    throw new FaultException<AtcWcfEntryNotFoundException>(
        new AtcWcfEntryNotFoundException(caseItem.InventoryItem.GetType(),
        caseItem.InventoryItem.Id));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just create the object based on the entity and select a record from the database?  If the fields don't match, this should raise an error, which is fine.  But for some reason mine is not.

Comment: How are you comparing? Because if you use `==` you are going to have a bad time. You should override `Equals` and implement comparison between instances of your entity.

Comment: What would you compare it with?  The object you create is based on entity.  You are trying to sync the model with the database at run time.  So I don't really think this would work.  Until you query the database your model will be valid.

Comment: When I call `Context.CaseItems.Where` I'm querying the database. The information I receive is the most up-to-date.